# "Press Any Key to Continue" function in C

Tags: c

How do I create a void function that will work as "Press Any Key to Continue" in C?

What I want to do is:

```
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
//The Void Function Here
//Then I will call the function that will start the game
```

I'm compiling with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the C Standard Library function `getchar()` instead as `getch()` is not a standard function, being provided by [Borland TURBO C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_C) for MS-DOS/Windows only.

```
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");  
getchar();
```

Here, `getchar()` expects you to press the return key so the `printf` statement should be `press ENTER to continue`. Even if you press another key, you still need to press ENTER:

```
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");  
getchar();
```

---

If you are using Windows then you can use `getch()`

```
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
getch();   
//if you press any character it will continue ,  
//but this is not a standard c function.
```

---

```
char ch;
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press ENTER key to Continue\n");    
//here also if you press any other key will wait till pressing ENTER
scanf("%c",&ch); //works as getchar() but here extra variable is required.
```

Comment: I can press 20000 keys, and if none of them are the Return key (or the "Any" key ;-), I can't continue. This won't be the right solution for this particular case.

Comment: I understand that. It was an exaggeration. My point was that the Return key must be pressed, meaning no matter how many keys you press, if none of them is the Return key, there is a problem because you are supposed to be able to press one key, regardless of what key it is, and the program should continue.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune indeed to mention these info.helpful comment[+1].thanks for pointing this.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune sorry for miss understanding of your first comment.

Comment: As a pedantic remark, those `printf` calls should probably be calls to `puts`. :-)

Comment: @MichaelRawson yes .`puts(str) ==>  printf("%s\n",str)`

Comment: @Gangadhar: I understand that. `puts` is faster, as it automatically adds the newline, and does not attempt to format its input as `printf` does. Just a thought, feel free to ignore.

Comment: @MichaelRawson Your suggestion helpful. it is good thought of using `puts` in this context.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone for your information! They have been a great help to me. I just wanted to ask, if I want to print some words after the "Press any key to Continue", will the code above all right to use? It seems like the words I want to print after the user pressed any key gets printed right below "Press Any Key to Contiune"

Comment: Yes ... you can print any thing after press any Key to continue.. add printf("what ever you want to print"); or printf("%s",word); or if there is  multiple words then use loop+ printf/puts after getchar()/getch(). There is user input in between press any key and the words you want to print. to avoid that you can use wherey()+gotoxy() in windows.if you are using UNIX based system you need to use user defined gotoxy() or else ncurses library.

Comment: If you use getch().you can also use \r ( carriage return ) when ever if you press any key other than RETURN . to avoid the user input in between press any key and words that you want to print.

Comment: The solution with `scanf` does not work in Windows (the program does not actually wait for a user to press `Enter`). Is there a cross-platform solution?

Comment: @Michael Rawson, Concerning `puts(str)` vs `printf("%s\n",str)`: For years now, good compilers will emit efficient code either way.  Use what is most clear in the context of the code.

Answer (score 21):

You don't say what system you're using, but as you already have some answers that may or may not work for Windows, I'll answer for POSIX systems.

In POSIX, keyboard input comes through something called a terminal interface, which by default buffers lines of input until Return/Enter is hit, so as to deal properly with backspace.  You can change that with the tcsetattr call:

```
#include <termios.h>

struct termios info;
tcgetattr(0, &info);          /* get current terminal attirbutes; 0 is the file descriptor for stdin */
info.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;      /* disable canonical mode */
info.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;          /* wait until at least one keystroke available */
info.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;         /* no timeout */
tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &info); /* set immediately */
```

Now when you read from stdin (with `getchar()`, or any other way), it will return characters immediately, without waiting for a Return/Enter.  In addition, backspace will no longer 'work' -- instead of erasing the last character, you'll read an actual backspace character in the input.

Also, you'll want to make sure to restore canonical mode before your program exits, or the non-canonical handling may cause odd effects with your shell or whoever invoked your program.

Comment: +1, though you might want to provide code to return to canonical mode... A single function that includes your code, gets a key press and returns to canonical mode would be a much more effective answer in my opinion. Still, it is a good contribution.

Comment: Probablly the easiest way is to keep a copy of the unmodified "info" structure you get from tcgetattr. That way you can just set it back to how it was before at the end of your function.

Comment: I just tried this without reading the entire comment, and it seems that nothing wierd happens if you dont restore canonical mode. Bash still works as intended, arrows search in bash history, can write commands, etc. Also probably opening a new terminal gets the default settings anyway i believe.

Comment: @bone: it depends on the shell.  bash manages terminal settings for itself and all processes it starts (it uses non-canonical mode internally for history stuff, sets canonical mode before launching processes, and restores stuff after they exit), so with bash you don't need to restore things.  Other (older) shells without job control do not do such terminal management.

Comment: Great answer. I didn't catch POSIX allowed to use ERASE to correct the input. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use `getch()`:

```
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
getch();
```

Windows alternative should be [_getch()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

If you're using Windows, this should be the full example:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
    printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
    _getch();
}
```

P.S. as [@Rörd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318877/rord) noted, if you're on POSIX system, you need to make sure that curses library is setup right.

Comment: getch is not in POSIX.

Comment: That does also mean, if you are on a POSIX system, you will need to set up curses correctly before you can use `getch`.

Comment: @SungMinKim Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
printf("Let the Battle Begin!\n");
printf("Press Any Key to Continue\n");
getch();
```

`getch()` is used to get a character from console but does not echo to the screen.

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 (The program which I use to code C) states that getch() is undefined..

Comment: I am using <stdio.h>, <stdlib.h> ,and <string.h>

Comment: Since in a comment you mentioned Visual Studio 2012, you have `<conio.h>`. The function you are looking for is `getch` as others have stated. You could also set up a loop and use `kbhit`, but you'll eat up CPU cycles that way without `Sleep` from the Windows API or whatever it is called these days, not to mention you might miss a key press if you make the thread sleep too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try more system independent methods:

```
system("pause");
```

Comment: This is literally the most system *dependent* function you can use, this call will only work on Windows and you should generally avoid `system` calls, they make your program very OS specific.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you are not using Linux you can use the `unistd.h`

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    system("pause");  
    return 0;
}
```

Output (in English):

```
Press any key to continue...
```

Comment: This will only work on Windows. Also, this functionality is not implemented in the standard library, it is implemented in an external program (`pause` in this case) because you are calling `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works in every OS

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myflush ( FILE *in )
{
  int ch;

  do
    ch = fgetc ( in ); 
  while ( ch != EOF && ch != '\n' ); 

  clearerr ( in );
}

void mypause ( void ) 
{ 
  printf ( "Press [Enter] to continue . . ." );
  fflush ( stdout );
  getchar();
} 

int main ( void )
{
  int number;

  // Test with an empty stream
  printf ( "Hello, world!\n" );
  mypause();

  // Leave extra input in the stream
  printf ( "Enter more than one character" );

  myflush ( stdin );
  mypause();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `clearerr ( in );` in `myflush()`?  Looks unnecessary and perhaps counter productive.