# C++ Program AutoClosing when Main() function completes

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I wrote a simple calculator program in C++ with Code::Blocks. When I compile the program, it runs fine through Code::Blocks, and ends with a press enter to continue, and then you can exit. However, when the exe is run manually, supose for a demo, then the program works fine but rather than a press enter to continue, the program autocloses.

My main() function (all the used functions are defined, it's not becuase of that) uses iostream library:

```
#include <iostream>
// all the other functions are defined here
int main()
{
    int input1 = getValueFromUser();
    int op = getOperationFromUser();
    int input2 = getValueFromUser();
    int result = getAnswer(input1, op, input2 );
    printResult(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Output from Code::Blocks (after main executes, and user has seen their answer)

```
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.930 s
Press any key to continue.
```

While running normally it simply autocloses, thereby not allowing the user to view their answer!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can run your program in debugging mode and place a breakpoint at the last brace `}` in `main()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: How's that better than running in the debugger with no breakpoints, which does what he wants?  The problem is running outside the IDE (which makes breakpoints impossible).

Comment: @TheCarver: Actually, when you see `Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 3.930 s` your program has already exited.  The window you see your program in is attached to Code::Blocks, and so it can stay open without your program.  If you start your program in, for example, a Command Prompt window (Start -> Run -> `cmd.exe`), then the window will also remain open even after your program quits, and allow you to see your output.

Comment: @BenVoigt when I run the exe by double clicking on it (which I want to be able to do), it autocloses. What can I do about that.

Comment: @TheCarver: When the window is created for your program, rather than under the control of Code::Blocks or cmd.exe, then the window closes when your program exits.  You can look at Rakete's answer for advice on delaying your program exit.  I'm just pointing out that what happened after the end of `main()` was not provided by your program to begin with, so its absence is not a bug.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add [SOLVED] to the title or edit the answer into your question. If you found an answer and want to share it, do so by using the space below designed for posting answers. It's totally acceptable to answer your own question here; see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for tips on how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, here is a non-portable solution (not recommended):

```
printResult(result);
system("pause"); //Shows a prompt, "Press any key to continue..."
```

If you would like to have a portable version (recommended), use

```
printResult(result);
std::cin.get(); //Waits for input, press enter to continue
```

Comment: Thanks!! For me, the non-portable solution works perfectly, but the portable std::cin.get() does not work. I would like to make this portable, as I need to send this to someone.

Comment: before what, exactly?

Comment: @TheCarver Sorry, call `std::cin.ignore();` before `std::cin.get();`, as there might be a trailing new line

Comment: std::cin.ignore();      std::cin.get();     return 0; like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use std::cin.Ingore();
this way:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not have any command to wait at the end of the execution. That's why it's not waiting. It justs prints the result and return 0, ending the `main` function immediately.

Add `getchar();` before `return 0;` and then the program will only exit after `ENTER` is pressed.

Reference: Gangadhar @ [StackOverflow - "Press Any Key to Continue" function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801483/press-any-key-to-continue-function-in-c). Sep 14, 2013.